# Conditional statement yields different results then If Then

Tags: .net, vb.net, conditional-statements

Trying to get to the bottom of a little mystery.

I have the following If Statement:

```
Dim myVal As Nullable(Of Guid)
myVal = If(vendor.Address.ID = Guid.Empty, Nothing, vendor.Address.ID)
```

The end value of `myVal` here is, inexplicably, `Guid.Empty`.

If I write that same code as follows:

```
Dim myVal As Nullable(Of Guid)
If(vendor.Address.ID = Guid.Empty) Then
  myVal = Nothing
Else
  myVal = vendor.Address.ID
End If
```

Why the difference?

Comment: Try this: `If(vendor.Address.ID.Equals(Guid.Empty), Nothing, vendor.Address.ID)`

Comment: @Blam Can you clarify what you mean?

Comment: @Blam: Could you clarify what you mean.  I thought I was doing 2, is that not the way Conditionals work in VB?

Comment: On second thought - I don't know.

Answer (score 3):

The problem is in how VB.NET infers types using the `If` operator. Both operands must be the same type. Given `Nothing` on one side and a `Guid` on the other, it assumes the result type should be a `Guid`, so it coerces the `Nothing` to `Guid.Empty`. Putting an explicit cast to `Nullable(Of Guid)` on either side will be enough tell the compiler that that's what you really want.

This should give you the results you expect:

```
Dim myVal2 As Nullable(Of Guid)
myVal2 = If(vendor.Address.ID = Guid.Empty, CType(Nothing, Nullable(Of Guid)), vendor.Address.ID)
```

Or this:

```
Dim myVal2 As Nullable(Of Guid)
myVal2 = If(vendor.Address.ID = Guid.Empty, Nothing, CType(vendor.Address.ID, Nullable(Of Guid)))
```

Comment: That's really interesting. Even `Option Strict` doesn't warn you of this behavior.

Comment: C# will raise a compiler error on `input == Guid.Empty ? null : input`. VB.Net is evidently more 'forgiving'.

Comment: @asawyer Thinking about it a bit more, I suppose it's because VB.Net considers `Nothing` to be roughly equivalent to the default value in certain context. E.g. `Dim foo As Guid = Nothing` is fine even under `Option Strict`, and compiles to `ldloca.s 00 ; initobj System.Guid`.